# How to make Javascript file use variable that was sent to Pug view

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, highcharts, pug

Okay so I am creating a website using Node. I am creating charts that use javascript (Highcharts), and so how I have it know is that the back-end is sending JSON data to the pug file "random" like so.

```
var data = require('../data.json')
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  //console.log(data);

  res.render('random', { title: 'Title', data: data });
});
```

The pug file then puts the data in the jquery script in order to create the chart. I do it this way so that I can eventually add functionality to where the JSON can be updated, but my problem is unrelated to this. I am wondering how I can clean up my code so that instead of embedding the script in the Pug file, I can put the script in a Javascript folder with all my scripts, and then use that to create the chart. The problem I am having is that since the JSON is sent to the Pug file, how can a separate Javascript file read that JSON data, and thus create the chart.

Comment: You just use a whatever = require('whatever') to the top of the file to include it if it is all server side programming, if that is not the case then you can use an AJAX request to retrieve the document on the client side if you want to do it dynamically, other wise you can use a <link> tag to import to load into memory along with the client side javascript. You can also write a controller script that runs all the other scripts and coordinates their behavior, which would include running the script that requires another script. Note that you must include Module.exports statements to export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed Pug variables in regular JavaScript; Pug has the ability to embed variables that it is given from `res.render`.

In your example, you'd have a variable named `data`.

```
script.
    var data = !{JSON.stringify(data)};
```

You need to call `JSON.stringify` on `data` first, otherwise Pug will render it as `[Object object]`. When you first stringify the JSON, you are essentially converting it to a string that your regular JavaScript will recognize as an object. If you were to do `typeof data`, it would return `object`.

From there, to use `data` in another file or function, you could just pass it to wherever it needs to go.

```
makeChart(data);
```